# Sublime Text 3: Node.JS Build System

Tags: node.js, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to make a Node.js build system for SB3 on Mac Yosemite. Here is my Node.Sublime-Build:

```
{   
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],   
  "selector": "source.js"   
}
```

Writing just 'node' returns an error, that node isn't found. I quickly checked in terminal "Which node" and it returned /usr/local/bin. I switched to the above code and now the build just returns "finished in x.0s".

Even if I simply console.log, it just returns "finished in x.0s".

Also, I checked that node is working on my computer (from console, and it is returning my console.log()s). What might I be missing?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit...ridiculous on my part. It seems you must first save the file before you can build system. I just wanted to test the environment and thought setting the build system would be enough.

Saving the file and then building solved the problem

*facepalm

Comment: Had the exactly same problem as you asked. Great solution!